WCF Service cannot be reached via https
I have configured a certificate to work with my WCF application but I still cannot access via https.
Even though my WCF is running.

Then I put the same thing inside my friend's laptop but it is running fine over his laptop What could be the possible reasons?
Please help me to solve this problem.

There are many reasons for your problem. If you're running fine on your laptop, the project itself should be fine. The problem should be on the certificate. Can you provide more details so that we can reproduce the problem?
